# How to get the result parameter of a NativeQuery

Tags: postgresql, gwt, postgis

I want to make this Query:

```
Select
    srid,
    substring(srtext
              from (position('DATUM["' in srtext)+7)
              for (position('ID["' in srtext)+2)
                - (position('DATUM["' in srtext)+7))
  from spatial_ref_sys
  order by substring
```

So, I create a

```
Query query = em().createNativeQuery(QUERY)
```

Also create a Srid object that has a Long srid and a String sridText.

I need to get those values and put into a List.
The substring on sridText, and obviously the srid into Long srid.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. First of all, I did a plpgsql function called getSrid

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getSRID() returns text[] as $$
declare
 resultado text[];
 consulta cursor for
 Select srid,substring(srtext from (position('DATUM["' in srtext)+7) 
 for(position('ID["' in srtext)+2)
  - (position('DATUM["' in srtext)+7)) as sub
 from spatial_ref_sys;
 cont int;
 i int;
 sridd int;
 srTextt text;
begin
 open consulta;
 i=1;
 EXECUTE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SPATIAL_REF_SYS' into cont;
 resultado := ARRAY[cont];
 while(i<cont) loop
  fetch consulta into sridd,srTextt;
  resultado[i] := sridd;
  resultado[i+1] := srTextt;
  i:=i+2;
 end loop;
 return resultado;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

As you see I got a Text[] on return so in my java call I cast the object to String[]:

```
public List<SridDTO> listaa(){
    int i = 0;
    List<SridDTO> list = new ArrayList<SridDTO>();
    Query query = em().createNativeQuery("Select getSrid()");
    String[] vector = (String[]) query.getSingleResult();
    while(i<vector.length){
        SridDTO sridDTO = new SridDTO(new Long(vector[i]),vector[i+1]);
        i = i + 2;
        list.add(sridDTO);
    }
    return list;
}
```